# Изучение языка программирования  PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать и какую литературу нужно изучить для использования `<? PHP+MSQL  $$ ?>`... заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: любая книга из разряда "php 4 dummies", упорство, мозг(или еще больше упорства) и быдлокодьте себе на здоровье

Comment: Не переходи на тёмную сторону силы. Если ты выбрал его как первый язык программирования, то он оставит в твоём мозге сложнобратимые изменения, которые удасться выветрить лишь с годами аккуратного кодинга на более продвинутом языке.

Comment: Мануал читай и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: Вы, если бы не знали программирования вообще так бы и поступали?

Чтобы мануал читать уже нужны какие-то, хоть и минимальные, но тем не менее - знания

Comment: @Vladimir VG, не разжигайте холивар!

php ничем не хуже остальных ЯП в своём деле, другое дело что многие применяют его не обдуманно.

Comment: @shurik, у пхп очень узкая область применения(сайты, причем легкие). Плюс лично мне он нравится как платформочка для разработки алгоритмов (чтоб первое время не заморачиваться с типами). Но если знать только его - это крест на программисте) Какой-нибудь C после него учить - это бессонные ночи и разбитая об стол голова)

Comment: Начинать следует с Гугла или местного поиска. На этом форуме вы отнюдь не первый, кто задавался этим вопросом.

Comment: > php ничем не хуже остальных ЯП в своём деле, другое дело что многие применяют его не обдуманно.

PHP объективно хреновый язык.

Есть ли какая-нибудь область или задача, которую он решает лучше других? Именно лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Я начинал с Робин Никсон "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, Javascript". Книга 2011 года, найти в сети можно. Легко читается, есть картинки с примерами, коды и многое другое. Учит основам, начинающим советую.

Comment: Больше всего мне нравится что SQL примеры там описаны с использованием консоли а не с ПыХаПыАдмина, что ИМХО - просто замечательно.

Вообще книга отличная, для того чтобы интересно начать - то что нужно.

Comment: Да, согласен примеры описаны с использованием консоли, но я для удобства работал в phpMyAdmin во вкладке "SQL". Та же самая консоль, только интерфейс удобней))

Comment: Спасибо за книгу Робина Никсона , но может еще есть литература которую можно читать параллельно??

Comment: JavaScript - подробное руководство, например

Comment: Начал чтение Робина Никсона добрался до установки WAMP на систему 
Winodws. Можно ли где то найти EasyPHP rus? и есть ли в этом какой не будь смысл ? либо качать EasyPHP по ссылке http://easyphp.org и не задавать глупых вопросов?

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит прочитать вот эту статью http://www.joomla-create.net/item/easyphp.html в ней указано, как настроить русский язык на EasyPHP, но сам я не устанавливал данный пакет. Я просто установил apache, модуль PHP и MySQL и все.

Comment: Нашел в меню русский извиняюсь , а то чуть не пошел по google и yandex

Answer (score 1):

Люк Веллинг и Лора Томпсон: "Разработка веб приложений на php и mysql". В инете можно скачать 3 издание и CD со всеми исходниками (из - за глав с уроками по разработке интернет магазина, почтовой службы и cms), а потом купить 4 издание, там этих глав нет, но есть интересный материал про ajax, jquery. Очень дельная книга.

Comment: Литературы я так понял надо прочитать не мало,но думаю оно этого стоит ...Спасибо дельные советы ))

Comment: @Зоркий, Коментарии к ответу нужны для уточнений, которые не следует писать в ответ. В ваших комментариях слишком много оффтопа. Старайтесь писать по делу.

Answer (score 1):

Самый легкий путь к познанию азов программирования лежит через хорошего учителя, т.к. книги на первом этапе вызывают много непонятных вопросов. Сейчас в интернете много хороших видеокурсов, могу порекомендовать как поверхностное изучение курсы Евгения Попова, он конечно не гуру в этом мощном языке но зато основы преподносит достойно. Еще есть Интуит.ру а на днях нашел вот такой  сайтик [ссылка](http://prog-school.ru)  думаю пригодится.

Comment: "Специалист: Видеокурсы по Интернет-технологиям"Нашел на просторах интернета.
 Общирный курс захватывает язык html;php;js;css;и тд.При просмотре видео такое чувство  что находишься  в аудитории.

Answer (score 0):

Начните изучение PHP с html. Как освоите верстку, хотя бы элементарную, приступайте к PHP. Хорошие книги издания БХВ-СПб. "PHP5 в подлиннике" к примеру. Потом посмотрите книгу "PHP5. Профессиональное программирование". Очень хорошая книга. Еще хорошая книга "PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования", но для нее уже необходимо знать хотя бы базу. Ну и параллельно с этим копайте в строну js.

Answer (score 0):

Неплохой видеокурс: Д. Науменко | PHP и CodeIgniter с нуля.